# How to handle project version?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, package.json

Does anyone know how to automatize app version upgrading?
I have to update it in package.json on each chganged.
Merge to main can be a triger, or simple comand in termianl.
Maby vsc has plugin to do the job?

Comment: You could absolutely write a quick command to do it. Seems like more work than just changing `package.json`, though. Do you want it to change version number on every commit, though?

Comment: I think the best way wolud be upgrading it on "git push origin main" command.